# What does the * next to gdb address mean?

Tags: gdb

In the following gdb output, what does the * next to the address mean?

```
(gdb) disas                                                  
Dump of assembler code for function _exit@plt:               
0x0804838c <_exit@plt+0>:       jmp    *0x8049774            
0x08048392 <_exit@plt+6>:       push   $0x10                 
0x08048397 <_exit@plt+11>:      jmp    0x804835c             
End of assembler dump.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The asterisk before the address indicates an indirect jump. So the jump target is not `0x8049774`, but the target is stored at the address `0x8049774`.